# What are the rules for template conversion operator type deduction in initializations?

Tags: c++, templates, language-lawyer, conversion-operator

Consider this code:

```
struct S
{
    template <typename T>
    operator T() const
    { return {}; }
};

struct R
{
    R() = default;
    R(const R&) = default;
    R(R&&) = default;
    R(bool) {}
};
```

Where on the [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.conv) are the rules defined for the following behaviors?

```
S s;
R r1 = s; // (1) passes: T = R
R r2(s);  // (2) ambiguity: T = R or bool?
```

Why doesn't (1) cause an ambiguity issue (given that `R` could be initialized by `bool` as well)? I've recently written an answer for a similar question, but I'm curious to why (1) doesn't behave like (2) in this context, and I don't know where it is described on the standard either.

Comment: There's no ambiguity at (1): You are only allowed **one** implicit user-defined conversion, and going via `R(bool)` would be *two* conversions. (In (2), the second conversion is explicit, so there is a genuine ambiguity.)

Comment: In case (1) there is only one match for the left hand side which is `operator=(R const&)` (which you did not specify and will therefore be default).  The right hand side will therefore be implicitly converted to `R`.  For (2) the left hand side has two matches `R(R const&)` and `R(bool)` which is ambiguous because both conversions are defined.

Comment: You can force an ambiguity on (1) as well by implementing `void R::operator=(bool) {}`.

Comment: @HenriMenke There is no consideration of any `operator=` involved at all.  Both are initialization, not assignment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8.5/15-16:

> The initialization that occurs in the `=` form of a *brace-or-equal-initializer* or *condition*, as well as ..., is called *copy-initialization*.
>
> The initialization that occurs in the forms

```
T x(a);
T x{a};
```

> as well as ... is called *direct-initialization*.

So `R r1 = s;` is copy-initialization, and `R r2(s);` is direct-initialization.  On to paragraph 17:

> - If the destination type is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type:
>
>   - If the initialization is direct-initialization, or if it is copy-initialization where the cv-unqualified version of the source type is the same class as, or a derived class of, the class of the destination, constructors are considered.  The applicable constructors are enumerated (13.3.1.3) and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3).
>   - Otherwise (i.e., for the remaining copy-initialization cases), user-defined conversion sequences that can convert from the source type to the destination type or (when a conversion function is used) to a derived class thereof are enumerated as described in 13.3.1.4, and the best one is chosen through overload resolution (13.3).

So direct-initialization looks at all the constructors of `R` and ends up being ambiguous, while copy-initialization explicitly tries to convert the expression to `R` directly and succeeds.